# Difficulties in grasping the proof of the Heine-Borel theorem

Tags: analysis

I’m finding it difficult to grasp a few nuances of the proof of the Heine-Borel theorem as laid out in my textbook. Here is the passage that is giving me problems:

“Suppose a set S is closed and bounded. Let *F* be an open cover of S. For each x∈R, let S<sub>x</sub>=S∩(∞,x] and let B={x: S<sub>x</sub> is covered by a finite subcover of *F*}. Since S is closed and bounded, S has a minimum (say, d). Then S<sub>d</sub>={d} and this is certainly covered by a finite subcover of *F*. Thus, d∈B and B is nonempty. If we can show that B is not bounded above, then it will contain a number z greater that the supremum of S. But then S<sub>z</sub>=S, and since z∈B, we can conclude that S is compact."

Below are a few points that I wish to have clarified.

i) When the author writes B={x: S<sub>x</sub> is covered by a finite subcover of *F*}, does he mean to say that 'a finite subcover of *F*' is some family of open sets *H* where *H*⊆*G* are both open covers of *F*, or that *H*⊆F?

ii) I would assume that S is compact because the author has found an open cover of S that has no finite subcover. In saying this, is he speaking of *F* or of B as being this particular open cover of S without a finite subcover?

Comment: $F$ is the open cover, $F = \{ U_\alpha : \alpha \in A\}$, where $A$ is some index set, and $U_\alpha$ is an open set, and $S \subset \bigcup\limits_{\alpha\in A}U_\alpha$. A finite subcover of $F$ is a finite subset $F_0 \subset F$ that also covers $S$ (resp., since in the proof the sets $S_x$ are considered, covers $S_x$). So $B$ is the set of all $x$, such that $S_x$ is contained in the union of some finite subfamily of $F$.

Answer (score 1):

(1) A finite subcover of an open cover $F$ of $S$ is a finite family $H \subseteq F$ whose union contains $S$. (I'm not sure what $G$ was supposed to be in the OP, but what I said is correct.)

(2) The question seems confused. The author wants to show that every open cover $F$ of $S$ has a finite subcover. Anyway, $F$ is the open cover in question. $B$ on the other hand is not a collection of open sets; it is a collection of elements of $\mathbb{R}$.